# Get local file while in Fullscreen mode

Tags: file, actionscript-3, air, fullscreen, filereference

I have swf that expands to fullscreen:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

The second I try to select local file, it's collapsing to NORMAL_SCREEN

```
    file_mask = new FileFilter("Images: (*.jpeg, *.jpg, *.png, *.JPG)","*.jpeg; *.jpg; *.png; *.JPG");
    local_file.browse([file_mask]);
```

Is it bug, or feature, or the way it used to be ???

```
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;

expand_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openApp)
function openApp(e:MouseEvent) {
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
}

file_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openApp2)
function openApp2(e:MouseEvent) {
    var local_file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    var file_mask:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images: (*.jpeg, *.jpg, *.png, *.JPG)","*.jpeg; *.jpg; *.png; *.JPG");
    local_file.browse([file_mask]);
}
```

Comment: Here you go. Open that in firefox or chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Use fullscreen interactive.

```
 stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
 //Align top left of the stage.
 stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
 //align swf contents without scale.
 stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

and if you are embeding in browser add the below parameters.

```
<param name="allowFullScreenInteractive" value="true" />
```

[Ref](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS58a13becbbb904c7-28cf6d32136e60de784-8000.html)